# Manually pausing an Aurora Serverless cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

An Amazon Aurora Serverless cluster can be configured to pause after a certain duration of inactivity: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.how-it-works.pause-resume

However, the shortest amount of time for which it can be configured to do so is 5 minutes.

This might not be sufficient for a frequent but predictable workload. Consider a case where the database is accessed for a few seconds every 10 minutes. With the database pausing 5 minutes after the last connection closes, that would result in a 50% cost saving over leaving the database constantly active.

In this sort of scenario, it would be nice if there were some way to prompt the database cluster into pausing - some way to say "okay, I'm done, you can pause now, no need to wait".

Either an API call that pauses the cluster or a way to reduce the timeout to less than 5 minutes would be perfect.

Is this possible?

Comment: If 5 min is the "shortest amount of time" then you can't change it. Otherwise, it wouldn't be the "shortest amount of time".

Comment: @Marcin It's the shortest in that AWS disallows setting that value to anything less than 300 seconds, but workarounds are the spice of life

Comment: If you use your dB so infrequently, why not host it your self on tiny instance or ecs container?

Comment: @Marcin You may have a point. I originally opted for Aurora Serverless over self-hosting with EC2 because I calculated that the monthly costs were about the same for me, and they are - but that's assuming that the billing granularity for EC2 usage is one hour, which for me would be effectively constant. I've just learned that it's actually one second for most instance types. This is definitely worth looking into! I may be able to self-host my own 'serverless' database, having my lambda spin it up and down as needed

Comment: Seems as good plan to try.